# want to alter field separator to allow spaces in particular data field

Tags: bash, awk

I want to hack a bash script that outputs a user's PIDs in a `yad` pop-up with option to select and `kill` PID if desired. But script uses `awk` to format data and I am unfamiliar with `awk`. I would use `sed` instead but data has 11 fields and `sed` only allows 9 buffers.

My problem with the `awk` format is the last field, `$11` is the command details and it gets chopped off after the first space in the description, which I don't want. I guess I might be able to replace all the spaces after the first 10, recognized as field separators to prevent command description details from getting lopped off after the first space. But that seems kind of hacky and I am sure there is a slicker way to do it with the `awk` command from the original script:

```
function gen_data() {

ps aux | tail -n +2 > "$TMPFILE" 
sed -ri "/$USER/!d" "$TMPFILE"
sed -ri "/$procName/!d" "$TMPFILE"
cat "$TMPFILE"

cat "$TMPFILE" | awk -F' ' '{print " " "\n" $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4 "\n" $5 "\n" $6 "\n" $7 "\n" $8 "\n" $9 "\n" $10 "\n" $11}' > "$OUTFILE" 
#`sed` edit
#cat "$TMPFILE" | sed -r 's/^([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}[^ ]*[ ]{1,}[^ ]*[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}([^ ]*)[ ]{1,}(.*)$/\1\n\2\n\3\n\4\n\5\n\6\n\7\n\8\n\9/' > "$OUTFILE" 
cat "$OUTFILE"

}
```

I wonder if anyone minds helping out on this?

**UPDATE:**
I managed to get the output I want by employing a `while` loop to change the first ten spaces in the `$TMPFILE` before `awk` processes it to tabs, which keeps all the spaces in the PID description in tact:

```
function gen_data() {

    ps aux | tail -n +2 > "$TMPFILE" 
    sed -ri "/$USER/!d" "$TMPFILE"
    sed -ri "/$procName/!d" "$TMPFILE"
    cat "$TMPFILE"
    cntr=10
    while [[ "$cntr" -gt 0 ]] ; do
        sed -ri 's/[ ]{1,}/\t/' "$TMPFILE"
        ((cntr--))
    done

    cat "$TMPFILE" | awk -F '   ' '{print " " "\n" $1 "\n" $2 "\n" $3 "\n" $4 "\n" $5 "\n" $6 "\n" $7 "\n" $8 "\n" $9 "\n" $10 "\n" $11}' > "$OUTFILE"
}
```

I would still be interested in any alternate/better ways it might be done?

Comment: What does the file look like and what are the parameters that you would like to extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

Sorry, I am being stupid today! You can just use `substr()` to get the command, like this, assuming it starts in column 70:

```
awk '{command=substr($0,70); print command}' $TEMPFILE
```

**ANOTHER OPTION**

You could also grab the command corresponding to a given process id (pid) like this:

```
ps -p <PID> -xo command=
```

And rather than deleting all lines not belonging to a given user (like you do with your `sed`), you could be more specific in the first place using a command like this:

```
ps -u <uid> -xo pid=,uid=,command=
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I think you could use the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable to tell `awk` where to split your fields, rather than using spaces. It is a GNU extension and I do not know the widths of the fields on your `ps aux` command so you will have to count them :-)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="14 8 6 6 6 8 6 8 6 8 200"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11}' $TMPFILE
```

Just make the width of the last field enormous to catch all the command.

Comment: ah yes, while trying to figure it out I did try adding a few additional params like: `$11 $12 $13 $14 $15` and it caught the additional details except they were ganged all toegther because all the spaces had been removed.

Comment: ah nm, looking closer at the `FIELDWIDTHS` option I can see it does not actually specify more than 11 fields just the width of those fields. I am pretty much `awk` illiterate but that's a kewl option to be sure.

Comment: D'oh, please have another look!

Comment: not sure, is the $0-$70 a range 70 possible input fields, most of which would likely not be populated with data, but a sort of catchall? I tried: `cat "$TMPFILE" | awk '{command=substr($1,70); print command}' > "$OUTFILE"` and the output in `yad` is a bunch of zero's without any alpha chars. I accepted you answer b/c the FIELDWIDTHS option does exactly what I need with some precise char calculation and in the end eliminates the need for my `while` loop.

Comment: In `awk`, $1 is the first field, $2 is the second and so on. $0 though, refers to the whole input line. So, `substr($0,70)` should give you characters 70 onwards of the whole line - I think you have mistyped `$1` instead of `$0`